# VmWare is not loading the further steps like registering the name,..etc

Tags: macos, vmware

Im using VMWARE 15 Pro.Installing mac os x mavericks is done. After install it will restart the os. After that it is not loading the further steps like registering the name,..etc.
Thanks in advance..
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we cannot run mac os in VMware..
I found the link...
[enter link description here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/464831)